# Magento 2.1 missing Web Setup Wizard link

Tags: magento2, installation, magento-2.1

Installed fresh Magento 2.1 store (php 7.0.8), with /pub as root web directory from command line and using tar.gz file. Everything seems to be fine, but when I go to admin panel under: System -> Tools the link for the "Web Setup Wizard" is missing.

/setup is aliased correctly on the webserver, and going directly to /setup while logged in as admin results in page saying "Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters. To use the Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard"

Am I missing something? Didn't see a bug/issue with this on github. Also, is setting the docroot to /pub still the recommended configuration?

Comment: Magento 2.1 is not yet stabled. So it is probably a bug! Should be fixed when the official version is out

Comment: It is officially released as of Thursday June 23. No longer an RC release.

Comment: We recommend you set the docroot to `/pub` in production to prevent access to the Setup Wizard. You should still be able to get it work so if it doesn't, open an issue in GitHub.

Comment: Looks like it's been reported on GitHub - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5247

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you noted this has been confirmed as an issue on Github here: github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5247

However this has been closed as it is a duplicate of: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4159

This issue thread also details a workaround until the fix is merged into the next Magento release, which is to switch your webserver root to that of the Magento root path, not the /pub subdirectory.

I have verified this works on CE 2.1 (you need to clean cache after this change), however I would personally not recommend using this workaround on a production environment as is less secure.

Answer (score 3):

"when you type http://www.shop.com/admin_xxxx/admin/backendapp/redirect/app/setup/ redirects to http://www.shop.com/setup/#/home and then all works as expected..."

this method doesn't work. still loops back to the same page...

Comment: Try https://domain/admin/admin/backendapp/redirect/app/setup/
The double up of admin in the url is not a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Here is temporary workaround for this issue to access Web Setup Wizard:

> when you type
>   http://www.shop.com/admin_xxxx/admin/backendapp/redirect/app/setup/
>   redirects to http://www.shop.com/setup/#/home and then all works as
>   expected...

Comment: This worked for me if paired with JohnHughes solution (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/127637/60128). Namely, change the webserver root AND manually type in the URL (as the link in the admin did not appear (and the Admin itself seemed to have lost all its CSS and JS)).

Comment: try incognito mode? worked here.. some session issues I think

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - this only happens when I am using google chrome, try an other browser I just tried it in opera and it works as expected, dont really understand why but it works "]