# Magento 2.1 Web setup wizard missing in backend

Tags: backend, magento-2.1

Running Ubuntu 16,04, Nginx, Mariadb, phpmyadmin, redis and Magento 2.1 GA

Why am I missing web setup wizard in backend?

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to know where you are.  Give us a screen shot of what you're seeing?

Comment: edit your question, do not post answers

Comment: More interesting than your server setup is: How did you install Magento?

Comment: please refer this link may help you.. [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262498/web-setup-wizard-option-missing-in-magento-2-3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262498/web-setup-wizard-option-missing-in-magento-2-3)

Answer (score 2):

This issue was also asked about [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122741/magento-2-1-missing-web-setup-wizard-link).

There was an issue opened on github for this.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5247