# Web Setup Wizard option missing in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

This option does not appear in my menu "System -> Tools". How can I do it appear? My user is admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment below line from this file:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.5/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Setup/MenuBuilder.php#L47-L47

```
$menu->remove('Magento_Backend::setup_wizard');
```